# dropdown navbar at bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

anybody can help me?, why my dropdown at navbar not working on localhost?

this is my navbar

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid theme-showcase" style="background-color: #87cefa;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigator</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" style="background-color: #fff;"><img src="asset/logo_header.png" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav style"> 
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>

         </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form"><a href="login_page.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Login</button></a>
        </form>
        </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

this is my include css on the page

```html
    <link rel="icon" href="asset/logo_header.png">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is my include javascript on the page

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck the paths to your external js and style files. They may not be applying correctly. In the example below I used the Bootstrap CDNs and everything seems to be working as expected.

`<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

change to

`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> // use this jquery instead
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>  // remove not needed if you are using the below line. 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Also, created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/xtru6sjy/1/) for review.

Let me know if that helps

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- HTML BEGINS -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid theme-showcase" style="background-color: #87cefa;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigator</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" style="background-color: #fff;">Brand Image</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav style"> 
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">action</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>

         </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form"><a href="login_page.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Login</button></a>
        </form>
        </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i change my include css and js in my file like your command and now my dropdown work correctly :D